# simple_form association not saving with attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, parameters, associations, simple-form

I have three models, car, service and appointment.

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :appointments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :service
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :service
end
```

And Im using simple form to create an appointment to a car referencing a service

```
<%= simple_form_for [@car, @appointment] do |a| %>
<%= a.input :date %>
<%= a.input :description, label: "descripción" %>
<%= a.input :location, label: "ubicación" %>
<%= a.association :service, as: :check_boxes, include_blank: false %>

<%= a.button :submit  %>
  <% end %>`
```

My appointment saves with the correct service, but the attributes of the service don´t

```
@car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
@appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)
@service = Service.new(params[ :service])

@appointment.service = @service
@appointment.car = @car

def appointment_params
  params.require(:appointment).permit(:date, :description, :location, :status, :requests, service_attributes:[:request, :price, :provider])
end
```

I think the problem is with the params, but im not sure and I don´t know if im saving them correctly, service_attributes:[:request, :price, :provider].

Thanks in advance!
(im using rails 5)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be going about this incorrectly. Since a `Service has_many :appointments` and an `Appointment has_many :services` (based on the comments), you have a m:m association and you might consider using `has_many :through`. Something like:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :appointments, dependent: :destroy
end

class AppointmentService < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :appointment
end

class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointment_services
  has_many :appointments, through: :appointment_services
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :car
  has_many :appointment_services
  has_many :services, through: :appointment_services
end
```

Now, you should be able to do something with that bit of your params:

```
"service_id"=>["", "2", "3"]
```

To create `appointment_services` (seems like you'll want to discard that `""`). You'll need to fiddle with it a bit and may be able to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointment_service` on `Appointment`.

Comment: jvillian yes im sure, as `Service` is a "menu" of services that an appointment can choose from, with set prices, providers, etc.. im sot sure if this is the best way to do though...

Comment: Hm. Okay, I see. Could you add the `params` that result from form submission to your question? I have a feeling `accepts_nested_attributes_for` may not be appropriate here.

Comment: Sure,    "appointment"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2018", "date(2i)"=>"7", "date(3i)"=>"26", "date(4i)"=>"15", "date(5i)"=>"21", "description"=>"prubeasny", "location"=>"", "service_id"=>["", "2", "3"]}, "commit"=>"Create Appointment", "controller"=>"appointments", "action"=>"create", "car_id"=>"8"}

Comment: What is bugging me is that "service_id"=>["", "2", "3"]  just saves the first one, and it doesn´t save its attributes (price, provider, etc)

Comment: It seems like your `Service`s should be created sometime prior to creating an `Appointment` (so that you can select from a menu of `services` when creating an `appointment`). Is that correct?

Comment: yes, they are created before, simple_form lets you choose which one via associations with check_box. When creating an appointment, you should be able to select your desired services

Comment: Yes, an `appointment` can include many `service`. and you are right, its creating many empty service instances every time :(